# Triangle Class C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I would appreciate any help that can be provided. I'm working on a class that evaluates a triangle based on three sides input. I'm fairly lost on some of the algorithms for the analysis, though. For example, I feel like my **largest**, **smallest**, and **type** of triangle algorithms are correct, but the first two are returning zeros and the type is returning that equilaterals are isosceles. Finally, I'm pretty much entirely lost on the **isTriangle** and **isRight**. I know they're wrong, but I can't figure out what adjustments to make. :/

```
#include "Triangle.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Triangle::Triangle()
{
    s1 = 1;
    s2 = 1;
    s3 = 1;
}

Triangle::Triangle(int x)
{
    s1 = x;
    s2 = x;
    s3 = x;
}

Triangle::Triangle(int x, int y, int z)
{
    s1 = x;
    s2 = y;
    s3 = z;
}

void Triangle::setSide1(int x)
{
    s1 = x;
}

void Triangle::setSide2(int x)
{
    s2 = x;
}

void Triangle::setSide3(int x)
{ 
    s3 = x;
}

int Triangle::getSide1()
{
    return s1;
}

int Triangle::getSide2()
{
    return s2;
}

int Triangle::getSide3()
{ 
    return s3;
}

int Triangle::perimeter()
{
    int perim = s1 + s2 + s3;

    return perim;

}

int Triangle::largestSide()
{
    int largest = 0;

    if (s1 >= s2 && s3)
        s1 = largest;
    else if (s2 >= s1 && s3)
        s2 = largest;
    else 
        s3 = largest;

    return largest;

}

int Triangle::smallestSide()
{
    int smallest = 0;

    if (s1 <= s2 && s1 <= 3)
        smallest = s1; 
    else if (s2 <= s1 && s2 <= s3)
        smallest = s2;
    else
        smallest = s3;

    return smallest;
}

bool Triangle::isRight()
{
    if (s3 == s1 + s2 || s2 == s1 + s3 || s1 == s2 + s3)

        return true;
    else
        return false;


}

bool Triangle::isTriangle()
{
    if (s1 + s2 < s3 || s1 + s3 < s2 || s2 + s3 < s1)

        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

string Triangle::typeTriangle()
{

    if (&Triangle::isTriangle == false)
        return "This is not a triangle";
    else if (s1 == s2 == s3)
        return "Equilateral";
    else if ((s1 == s2 && s1 != s3 && s2 != s3) || (s2 == s3 && s2 != s1 && s3 != s1))
    return "Isosceles";
    else if (s1 != s2 && s2 != s3)
        return "Scalene";



}
```

Comment: s1 = largest; making the members const shows things line this.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the definition of a triangle to determine how best to classify them. (Especially the trigonometric functions.) Remember triangles are defined by both their ANGLES and SIDES. As of now you are only assessing the sides.

Comment: Doesn't `s1 == s2 == s3` equal `(s1 == s2) == s3` in C++? (I.e. you would compare `s3` to `0` or `1`).

Comment: @Kevin Check out this link, I think you will greatly benefit from learning more about trigonometry: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry

Comment: A triangle is uniquely determined by the three sides. No need to consider the angles too.

Comment: Smallest side has a bug where you compare with 3 rather than s3

Comment: @Bathsheba true enough, but (looking at isRight) it is generally the easiest way to determine this by utilizing the trigonometric functions. You could also use the "Pythagorean Theorem" which is a simplification from the law of cosines. Regardless I think he will find great value is exploring these possibilities. EDIT: It appears to me this is likely a task of educational nature, and it seems the ask-er is inexperienced with trigonometric concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If S1 == s2 == s3 is true that does not imply the sides are equal.

You need to write s1 == s2 && s1 == s3

To see this, rewrite to booleans. Set b1 false and b2 not equal to b3.

B2 == b3 is false and that will compare true with b1. Oops.

Your triangle has a right angle if and only if the square of the longer side is the sum of the squares of the shorter sides.

Comment: Don't you mean s1 == s2 && s1 == s3